# Emmet - use custom snippet to auto-complete data-attributes

Tags: autocomplete, adobe-brackets, emmet

I am trying to create a **custom snippet** in Emmet for **data-attributes**.

I know, when I type:

```
div[data-reveal]
```

it will result in

```
<div data-reveal=""></div>
```

but I also would like to have a snippet for the attribute itself. So the workflow would be. Create "div[rev]" and hit tab with the cursor right after rev and then expand the whole snippet:

```
  div[rev] -> div[data-reveal] -> <div data-reveal=""></div>
```

I have added the following line to the snippets.json file
"rev": "data-reveal",
but at the moment I get:

```
 div[rev] -> div[<data-reveal></data-reveal>]
```

I am using Emmet with Brackets, I have looked into extensions like backets-snippets but the workflow is not what I am looking for. I would like to do it in Emmet. Thanks!

Comment: The name of the snippet should be `div-rev` or something. You can’t use dynamic abbreviation as snippet name.

Comment: I have found the solution, I wrongly placed my snippet inside snippets.json under abbreviations and not under snippets, where its supposed to be. Now, if I hit tag after rev it will turn into data-reveal without being changed into a tag.